# Urban fantasy book series with female lead who has a dirty talking parrot that has lost its feathers

Tags: story-identification, books, urban-fantasy

I am looking for a book I started reading fairly recently. I can only remember a few details.

The female lead has a dirty-talking parrot that has lost its feathers. In the beginning of the book she is offered a job in law enforcement in a new town.

I also seem to remember that her mother was abusive to her when she was younger. The mother seemed to think her daughter was evil?

I vaguely remember the female lead has nullification powers which manifested when she started her period for the first time. Also the female lead is possibly a redhead (not sure if I’m getting this detail mixed up with another book).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You've identified this as an urban fantasy novel, but are there any overtly fantastic elements?  You've mentioned that someone (your antecedents are unclear) thought her daughter was the devil, but was that just a delusional belief or was there some truth to it?

Comment: Is "a dirty talking parrot" a dirty parrot that talks or a parrot that talks dirty?

Comment: Nothing sticks out in the TV Tropes entry at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FowlMouthedParrot

Comment: Also, nothing jumps out at https://www.reddit.com/r/RomanceBooks/comments/zqcj5v/romance_with_a_dirty_talking_pet_parrotcockatoo/

Comment: What job in law enforcement? Sheriff or private detective or what?

Comment: You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 12):

Probably *Special Monsters Unit* (2023) by Eve Langlais, first book of the "Earth's Nexus" series.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/63282838-special-monsters-unit):

> Some people are born to greatness. **My mother wanted to strangle me at birth.**
>
> I’ve not had an easy life, not in a world that thrives on magic. Spells to reinforce buildings. Hexes to give you the face of a supermodel.
>
> Or so I’ve been told.
>
> No one can hide their true face from me, and people get ugly when they find out my presence is the reason magic shrivels and dies.
>
> It’s not as cool as it sounds, so **when I’m offered a job with the Special Monsters Unit, I take a chance and join a misfit crew** to find out why the town of Nexus is a magnet for cryptids.

The parrot is *Wally*, and he's actually a cockatoo who is also a half [caladrius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caladrius). He is partially bald due to his magical feathers being plucked out.

> “Who’s a fucker got to shank to get fed?” Wally complained.
> It should be noted I didn’t teach him to talk like this. I’d found Wally in a cage at the back of an apothecary dealing in illegal substances, all of his feathers plucked. While only half caladrius, his white feathers were rare enough to still be prized and useful in healing potions. Even once I saved him, they never grew back fully, meaning he sported bare spots all over. Add in his somewhat colorful vocabulary and the rescue center who took him in said he’d most likely end up euthanized or released into the wild with the same effect, given he couldn’t actually fly with his docked wings.

The cover has a redhead woman.

[image: book cover, dark theme, redhead woman in a black crop top, next to a werewolf-like creature]

---

Found with the Google query `urban fantasy book dirty parrot site:goodreads.com/book`.